# Spring overrides bean configuration setting its "Primary" one

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Using Spring 3.X.X I have 2 services annotated with @Primary and I created another configuration class where I want to use a "customised" version of one of the services.

For some reason I ignore while debugging the configuration class I see that it gets the correct dependencies but when I want to use it it has setup the wrong ones.

I find it easier to explain with code, here is an example:

Interface Foo:

```
public interface Foo {
    String getMessage();
}
```

Primary implementation with a default message hardcoded:

```
@Primary
@Service("FooImpl")
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    private String message = "fooDefaultMessage";

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Bar interface:

```
public interface Bar {

    void doBar();
}
```

Bar default implementation:

```
@Primary
@Service("BarImpl")
public class BarImpl implements Bar {

    private Foo foo;

    @Override
    public void doBar() {
        System.out.println(foo.getMessage());
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

So far so good, if I want to Inject a Bar I get everything as expected. Thing is I have a Configuration with the following:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("readOnlyFoo")
    Foo readOnlyFoo() {
        FooImpl foo = new FooImpl();
        foo.setMessage("a read only message");
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("readOnlyBar")
    Bar readOnlyBar() {
        BarImpl bar = new BarImpl();
        bar.setFoo(readOnlyFoo());
        return bar;
    }
}
```

When I want to inject a readOnlyBar I am getting the default Foo instead of the one set up here.

```
private Bar readOnlyBar;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("readOnlyBar")
public void setReadOnlyBar(Bar readOnlyBar) {
    this.readOnlyBar = readOnlyBar;
}

...
readOnlyBar.doBar();
```

Has the Foo bean with "fooDefaultMessage". Why is that? How can I make sure Spring uses the Bean I set on the @Configuration?

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT:** Note that the same happens if instead of calling the readOnly() method in the @Configuration class you pass a @Qualified argument. i.e.:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("readOnlyFoo")
    Foo readOnlyFoo() {
        FooImpl foo = new FooImpl();
        foo.setMessage("a read only message");
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("readOnlyBar")
    Bar readOnlyBar(@Qualifier("readOnlyFoo") Foo readOnlyFoo) {
        BarImpl bar = new BarImpl();
        bar.setFoo(readOnlyFoo);
        return bar;
    }
}
```

If instead I try using Constructor dependency injection everything works as I want/expect but unfortunately I can't use that.

Comment: can't you use profiles for this?

Comment: Not sure how profiles would help here. Yes, I could have one profile using the default implementations and another one that points to the read only ones. The question is how to set the read only one instantiating new (read only) beans from the default.

Answer (score 3):

As @yaswanth pointed out in his answer, the problem was that the `foo` property was overwritten by property injection happening after the creation of the bean.

One way to get around that is to use constructor injection for the `BarImpl` instead of property injection. That would make your code look like...

```
@Primary @Service("BarImpl")
class BarImpl implements Bar
{
    private Foo foo;

    @Autowired
    public BarImpl(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

and your configuration would be...

```
@Configuration
class BeanConfiguration 
{
    @Bean @Qualifier("readOnlyFoo")
    Foo readOnlyFoo() {
        FooImpl foo = new FooImpl();
        foo.setMessage("a read only message");
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean @Qualifier("readOnlyBar")
    Bar readOnlyBar(@Qualifier("readOnlyFoo") Foo readOnlyFoo) {
        return new BarImpl(readOnlyFoo);
    }
}
```

As a side track; you should also make sure to use dependency injection in you factory methods instead of calling the factory method explicitly, or you will end up with multiple instances of your beans...

Good luck with your future endeavours!

Comment: Although I knew this, as it is written in the question, it is the closest answer to what I needed and the bounty is about to end, therefore I chose this answer to receive the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `@Autowired` on an instance variable and set that in an `@Bean` method like you did. Part of spring life cycle goes this way

Bean definitions scanned => Bean instances created => Post Processors called => .....

In your example,

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("readOnlyBar")
Bar readOnlyBar() {
    BarImpl bar = new BarImpl();
    bar.setFoo(readOnlyFoo());
    return bar;
}
```

`readOnlyBar` bean gets created and because `readOnlyFoo()` is called from within this method, `readOnlyFoo` bean also gets instantiated. Till this point, `readOnlyBar` has `readOnlyFoo` in its instance variable. Once the bean is instantiated, `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is called which scans the class of bean (`BarImpl` in this case) for any `@Autowired` annotations on instance variables or methods. It finds them and tries to inject the beans into the corresponding variables using field injection or setter injection (wherever the `@Autowired` annotation is present). In this case since we have `@Autowired` setter and did not specify the `@Qualifier` annotation, spring injects the `@Primary` bean which is the `defaultFooMessage` bean.

AFAIK, there is no straightforward way to configure in spring for `@Bean` methods to take priority over Autowiring.

Instantiating all beans with `@Bean` methods will fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's better to use @Bean("beanName") instead of two annotations: Bean and Qualifier. And I'm not sure does Qualifier work for naming beans. Anyway you should write the code in one style. So if you use value attribute in @Service annotation you should use value attribute in @Bean annotation.

Create field `@Autowired List<Foo> allFoos` and look at it in debug mode. You will see all you Foo beans so you can check their names.